# Python script that can run from OSX Finder and Windows Explorer

Tags: python, macos, finder

I have a bunch of useful Python3 scripts that I use in different OS environments. They run fine when called from the terminal but I want to run them from both Windows Explorer and OSX Finder. In Windows, that is not an issue as the *.py files get associated with the installed interpreter.

For OSX, I am having some problems. I tried using the shebang line.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

But Finder doesn't recognize it as a script. How do I make Finder recognize *.py files as scripts? I am interested in maximum portability with as few OS modifications as possible.

Also I explicitly specified the interpreter location above. It will be in different locations for different OSes. Is there a way to make it multi-OS so that if it doesn't find it in one location, it will try another? Say if I want to run it from one of Ubuntu's GUI File Manager.

EDIT: Here's more info on my use case. I want to go to a new computer and git clone my repo of Python3 scripts and be able to run them from within the GUI file manager with minimal changes to the new computer.

Comment: Your title says iOS finder btw, change that to osx or else you'll confuse people (like me)

Comment: Im not sure but I think you have to run `chmod +x file` to make it executable

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the title. I want it to associate it with all *.py not just one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the script more portable use `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as shebang. Side effect will be that it will run the first python3 interpreter it finds in the $PATH ([Unix StackExchange question on that subject](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my))

---

To run the script from the finder try to chmod the file. i.e. 
`chmod +x FILE`

---

Found another possibility here: [Link to the Blog](http://skillfulness.blogspot.de/2010/12/how-to-run-python-script-from-mac-os-x.html)

1. Make this the first line of your Python script "#!/usr/bin/env python"
2. Change the extension of the script file to ".command" i.e. my_python_script.command
3. In Terminal make the Python script file executable by running "chmod +x my_python_script.command"
4. Now when you double click the Python script in Finder it will open a terminal window and run.

---

Alternative I found would be this but it needs system modification: [Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/593364/run-python-script-from-finder-rather-than-edit)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't quite answer the question completely. I have added more information on my use case.

Comment: I found the last few links earlier too. Renaming it to *.command is not ideal as the script won't be recognized on Windows then. It seems the best approach would be to write a bash file that traverses the entire directory chmod'ing all the *.py files. That way, I get to a new computer, git clone it, then run the bash script to setup everything.

Comment: Usually the cmod flag should stay if you push from a Unix system. If you edit the file and push from a windows system the flag gets removed.